# Sign in with Facebook Flutter, how can I change my code?

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter

How can I change my code below so I can login with Facebook? The second method is just normal login, but I want apply the same app login logic to the Facebook login.

```
// facebook login
     bool isLoggedIn = false;

      void onLoginStatusChanged(bool isLoggedIn) {
        setState(() {
          this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
        });
      }

      void initiateFacebookLogin() async {
        var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
        var facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
        switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
          case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
            print("Error");
            onLoginStatusChanged(false);
            break;
          case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
            print("CancelledByUser");
            onLoginStatusChanged(false);
            break;
          case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
            print("LoggedIn");
            onLoginStatusChanged(true);
            break;
        }
      }



    // application login
          void login() async {
            if (loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
              loginFormKey.currentState.save();
              repository.login(user).then((value) {
                //print(value.apiToken);
                if (value != null && value.apiToken != null) {
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text(S.current.welcome + value.name),
                  ));
                  Navigator.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext)
                      .pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
                } else {
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text(S.current.wrong_email_or_password),
                  ));
                }
              });
            }
          }
```

Comment: What do you mean by same logic? Do you mean authenticating your Facebook user on the server side?

Comment: yes exactly, i want to store it to the server and then push to the homepage as a registered user and fetch all users  data

Comment: Well, that will depend on your server-side language but generally, you will have to send the access token(`facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token`) gotten from this Facebook plugin to the server side and then use the details provided over there. E.g for express.js, you can make use of `passport-facebook-token` if you use passport for authentication.

Comment: Understand, Thank you very much